# mvc save file to folder in site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I'm trying to save files to a folder in my site, but I keep receiving an UnauthorizedAccessException error.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Product product, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        var img = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/productImages/"),
                                        System.IO.Path.GetFileName(image.FileName));
                image.SaveAs(path);
                product.ImageName = img;

            }

            // save the product
            repository.SaveProduct(product);
            // add a message to the viewbag
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", product.Name);
            // return the user to the list
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            // there is something wrong with the data values
            return View(product);
        }
    }
```

**HERE IS THE VIEW**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, 
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {

    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <div class="editor-label">Image</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @if (Model.ImageName == null) {
            @:None
        } else {
            <img width="150" height="150" 
                src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product", new { Model.ProductID })" />
        }
        <div>Upload new image: <input type="file" name="image" id="image"/></div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel and return to List", "Index")
}
```

I'm receiving the error on the **image.SaveAs(path);** line

I can't see what exactly I'm doing wrong. Any help?

Comment: Check your IIS user permissions for the folder you're saving to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a permission problem

Change the Permissions on `productImages` folder so that ASP.NET can write to that.